# angular 1.4.0 and selects: I don't understand the breaking change

Tags: angularjs

Yesterday angular 1.4.0 was released.
The changelog states that there is a breaking change with "selects".

I used to use selects like this:

controller code:

```
// Default initial selection
$scope.filters = {
    someFilter: false
};
```

view code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Filter...</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="filters.someFilter">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="true">is true</option>
        <option value="false">is false</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the select would start with the option "is false" selected.

Now, with angular 1.4.0, that is not the case:
The selected option is "blank". I see two blanks in the rendered view (instead of one, as I did before)

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'd say it's because `"false"` does not equal `false`

Comment: I tried using "false" in the controller but it didn't work

Comment: also tried using `{{false}}` and `{{true}}` in the value of the option (in the view)

Comment: Works fine using the string `"false"` ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/kj8mxEqh3vfuJp5Yv6b9?p=preview

Comment: @Phil you are right, although theres a little difference that is the key for it to not work: I also have the blank option in my view

Comment: Oops, don't know where that went. Fixed now

Comment: oh! it works!.. so at the end it wasnt necesary to create the options programatically

Comment: No, but the strings `"false"` and `"true"` are nowhere near as useful as a boolean value

Comment: I'm sending them as parameters in an ajax request.. so, they are useful as strings there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)...

> The value of a `select` directive used without `ngOptions` is always a string.

Essentially, you are trying to compare the string `"false"` with the boolean `false`.

One possible solution is to use `ngOptions`, eg

```
$scope.options = [
    { val: true, label: 'is true' },
    { val: false, label: 'is false' }
];
```

and in your template

```
<select ng-model="filters.someFilter"
        ng-options="opt.val as opt.label for opt in options">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VszT5TgtVStdIc8PRrqp?p=preview)</kbd>

---

Alternatively, you could just use strings in your model, eg

```
$scope.filters = {
    someFilter: "false"
};
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kj8mxEqh3vfuJp5Yv6b9?p=preview)</kbd>